# What's wrong with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

`INSERT` doesn't work, not sure why.

db.php:

```
function check($value)
{
    if ($value)
        return htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($value)));
    else
        return null;
}

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'cart';

$connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ('no connect');
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ('no db');

function add($name, $price, $description, $image)
{
    global $connect;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO items (name, price, description, image)
            values ('{$name}', '{$price}', '{$description}', '{$image}');";
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

    if (!$query)
        die(mysql_error());

    mysql_close($connect);
}
```

add.php:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
include_once('./db.php');

$name = check($_POST['name']);
$price = check($_POST['price']);
$description = check($_POST['description']);
$image = check($_POST['image']);

if ($name && $price && $description && $image)
{
    add($name, $price, $description, $image);
    echo 'sent';
}
```

When I get `sent` message, I've no new rows in `items` table. I check it using phpmyadmin.

DB is created using this code (by install script):

```
function reset_mysql()
{
    global $connect;

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE items (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        price VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        description VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        image VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        primary key (id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

    $query = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

    if (!$query)
        die(mysql_error());

    mysql_close($connect);
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What's the data type of each?  Maybe `price` is numeric and doesn't need quotes?  BTW, look into *script injection attacks* when you have some free time.

Comment: On a side note, you should be using `mysqli_*` now instead of `mysql_*`

Comment: Is image a file upload or a string value?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: `$name && $price && $description && $image` => one of those equates to false most likely.

Comment: You also need to be using `mysql_real_escape_string()` on those variables. That said you shouldnt be using that mysql api at all as Quentin mentioned.

Comment: @Mike Christensen I use one more function to prevent injections, it gives no error. The most important part is to make this code work, price would be translated into float then.

Comment: OMG, get off the `mysqli_*` high horse.

Comment: @Rawkode no, its a simple string like "car.jpg"

Comment: Love your title... But you'd better ask what is *right* with MySQL

Comment: @Wrikken but a get `sent` message after validation. Seems the dark is on the other side.

Comment: I've added a function I use to prevent injections, its name is `check`

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the obsolete api. Would use them when I understand what's wrong with the current code. I would like to know how can I make it work.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I wasn't talking to you specifically. Just saying, web dev moves so quickly it's hard for those who just learned one thing to find out they have to learn a whole new thing.

Comment: @Mike Brant I get no errors, even after `INSERT INTO`, too strange.

Comment: @Steve - Maybe the transaction isn't being committed?

Comment: What does `$query`returns ? Are you sure `price` column is a `string` ?

Comment: @bobthyasian: Its not a high horse thing. You shouldnt be using it for new dev even if it wasnt deprecated. PDO and Mysqli are superior and easier to work with once you know them. He shouldnt have even learned ext/mysql, but until google starts yielding on mysqli or PDO tutorials when people search its going to be a rough battle. Mentioning its deperecated and what not as much as possible is part of fighting that battle.

Comment: I test it using `something` as a value for all the `$_POST` variables. No error, no new row in the `items` table.

Comment: @Mike Christensen how do I check it?

Comment: @Steve Do you actually have `error_reporting` turned on? Is `display_errors` on?

Comment: @Steve - Try adding `COMMIT;` to the end of your SQL statement?

Comment: add('something', 'something', 'something', 'something'); =>>> Warning: mysql_query(): 4 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in V:\home\dev\www\Steve\db.php on line 23

Comment: Line 23 is $query = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

Comment: Not sure where do I got `4`, there is no such number in the code.

Comment: If you're already connected to the DB and selected table, you don't need to specify `$connect` in your query.

Comment: @bobthyasian I replaced `$connect` to the `add` function and it began to work. Thanks!

Comment: Seems that `mysql_close($connect)` inside a function doesn't work nice with the global `$connect`.

Answer (score 0):

> $sql = "INSERT INTO items VALUES ('', '$name', '$price', '$description', '$image')";

UPDATED

Comment: That is good coding style advice, but what he has is not wrong.

Comment: INSERT INTO items (name, price, description, image) values (sometext, sometext, sometext, sometext);>>Unknown column 'sometext' in 'field list' for values ($name, $price, $description, $image)

Comment: No errors for values ('{$name}', '{$price}', '{$description}', '{$image}')

Comment: Same result, no new rows in `items` table

Comment: @MikeBrant There is a problem with using just quotes when you are trying to use variables that are multidimensional arrays eg. one_array['name'][$i]

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed by replacing `mysql_connect` to the `add` function:

```
function add($name, $price, $description, $image)
{
    global $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name;

    $connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ('no connect');
    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ('no db');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO items (name, price, description, image)
            values ('{$name}', '{$price}', '{$description}', '{$image}');";
    $query = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

    if (!$query)
        die(mysql_error());

    mysql_close($connect);
}
```

Thanks for all of the comments, you're awesome!

Comment: do move onto mysqli_ ASAP... rewrite your db.php file to be more reusable, this file is going to be a mess if need to run many queries.